# How to stop page loading when click on F5

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, safari, spring-security, hdiv

How to stop the page loading when click on F5...

Thanks & Regards

Rubina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE and FireFox

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Block F5 Key In IE & Mozilla</title>

<script language="JavaScript">

    var version = navigator.appVersion;

    function showKeyCode(e) {
        var keycode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

        if ((version.indexOf('MSIE') != -1)) {
            if (keycode == 116) {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                event.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (keycode == 116) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

 </script>

</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:document.body.focus();" onkeydown="return showKeyCode(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,i followed the same as your answer,but i am still facing the same problem.it is redirecting to the error page,i have to stay in MENU page even if i click on refresh.

Comment: Sorry dear ,i don't have any idea about safari browser,but i will try for you,and if got answer ,i will definitely let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to disable location.reload() by overriding it as:

```
location.reload = function() {return false;}
```

But this may have other side-effects...