# Prevent default on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I need to redirect user to another URL after pressnig F5, but instead of it, browser asks me to post HTML form data again. How could I do this using JQuery or JS?

Comment: are you posting to the same page and put a die at the end..???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to avoid the submit due to a refresh of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690541/best-way-to-avoid-the-submit-due-to-a-refresh-of-the-page)

Comment: yes, i have HTML form on that page

Comment: Firstly, handle the browser refresh event and then write your redirection code. Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418803/how-to-stop-page-loading-when-click-on-f5

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
location.replace("url here")
});
```

On loading the page we can direct to different url by using jquery

Comment: Please explain your solution a little